# Filter array by value from query params

Tags: ember.js

I have a list of posts and I need filter by `social_network`, I'm using query params to filter, my question is how temporary filter the model so that later I can come back to show all

**route posts.index with:**

```
model(params) {
    return this.store.find('post');
  }
```

and also a **controller** for it:

```
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  queryParams: ['social_network'],
  social_network: 'all',

  paramsDidChange: function() {
    var network = this.get('social_network');
    var posts = this.get('model');

    if(network === 'all') {
      return posts;
    }
    return posts.filterBy('social_network', network);
  }.observes('social_network', 'model'),
});
```

**View**

```
{{#each post in model}}
    <li>
      {{post-index post=post}}
    </li>
  {{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowadays it's recommended to use [computed properties](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.15/namespaces/Ember.computed) for this functionality. Both `.property` and `.observes` are being deprecated.

I've adjusted the example from the Ember docs to an answer to your question.

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { computed } from '@ember/object';

export default Controller.extend({
  queryParams: ['socialNetwork'],
  socialNetwork: null,

  filteredPosts: computed('socialNetwork', 'model', function() {
    const socialNetwork = this.get('socialNetwork');
    const posts = this.get('model');

    if (category) {
      return posts('socialNetwork', socialNetwork);
    } else {
      return posts;
    }
  })
});
```

In the template you would use the `filteredPosts` property. Eg.

```
{{#each post in filteredPosts}}
  <li>
    {{post-index post=post}}
  </li>
{{/each}}
```

For more information see the official docs on [Specifying Query Parameters in Ember](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.18.0/routing/query-params/#toc_specifying-query-parameters).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an observer - just use a computed property in the controller and loop through the computed property in the template.

Your computed property in the controller would look as follows:

```
filteredStuff: function() {
  var network = this.get('social_network');
  var posts = this.get('model');

  if(network === 'all') {
    return posts;
  }

  return posts.filterBy('social_network', network);
}.property('social_network')
```

Then, in your template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <ul>
  {{#each item in filteredStuff}}
    <li>{{item.title}}</li>
  {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>
```

Working solution [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gikeba/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: My bad, I was trying this way but instead of `.property` using `.observable`, which resulted in an error. thanks for help.